# Configuring ODBCLogging on IIS 7.5

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7.5

I have followed the link https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/odbclogging and did the following:

1. installed odbclogging as instructed
2. executed %windir%\System32\inetsrv\logtemp.sql as instructed
3. in cmd i executed the following after changing the values accordingly:

appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site"
-section:system.webServer/odbcLogging /dataSource:"InternetDb" 
/commit:apphost

appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site"
-section:system.webServer/odbcLogging /tableName:"InternetLog" /commit:apphost

appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site"
-section:system.webServer/odbcLogging /userName:"InternetAdmin" /commit:apphost

appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site"
-section:system.webServer/odbcLogging /password:"P@ssw0rd" /commit:apphost

appcmd.exe set sites "Default Web Site" -logFile.logFormat:"Custom" /commit:apphost

appcmd.exe set sites "Default Web Site" -logFile.customLogPluginClsid:"{FF16065B-DE82-11CF-BC0A-00AA006111E0}" /commit:apphost

4. I then clicked on a few links on the website, checked the InternetLog table, and it has no records.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to use ODBC logging myself. After following the instructions you mentioned, nothing was logged.

I couldn't find much information about ODBC logging online, I guess because you shouldn't really use it. But one of my IIS 8 books mentions:

> **CustomLoggingModule** - Loads custom log modules, which can be used to
>   generate custom-formatted logs. Microsoft’s ODBC logging option is
>   implemented as a custom log extension.

So it seems for ODBC logging to work, you also need to have the CustomLoggingModule installed, which I didn't.

After running:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online FeatureName IIS-CustomLogging
```

or on Servers pre-2012:

```
dism.exe -online -enable-feature -featurename:IIS-CustomLogging
```

the odbc logging worked for me.

Comment: Just tried installing CustomLogging as it wasn't installed.  After the installation, I went to the website, and the website stopped working.  I was getting an error message.   Restarting the server did not make a difference after installation.  I had to uninstall CustomLogging, restart, and the website was back up and running again.